# Cannot sort a single linked list in C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I have a trouble with sorting the linked list. In main() I add 7 items to linked list, and I try to sort them using selection sort. I tried debugging and going step by step but could not find where things went wrong.

```
#define LARGE 40

struct Node 
{
    char password[LARGE];
    int score;
    struct Node *next;
};
struct Node *front = NULL, *rear = NULL;

/* function to swap data of two nodes a and b*/
void swap(struct Node *a, struct Node *b) 
{ 
    int temp = a->score; 
    char temp2[150];
    strcpy(temp2, a->password);
    a->score = b->score;
    strcpy(a->password, b->password);
    strcpy(b->password, temp2);
    b->score = temp; 
}

void selectionsort(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *first,*second,*temp;
    
    int i,j,N;
    N= 7;
    printf("%u\n",front->score);
    
    first = head;
    second = first->next;
    
    for(i=0;i<N-1;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<N;j++){
            if(first->score > second->score){
                swap(first,second);
            }
            second = second->next;
            printf("%u\n",front->score);
        }
        first = first->next;
        printf("%u\n",front->score);
    }
    printf("%u\n",front->score);
}

int main()
{
    char value1[40] ="abcdefg";
    int valscor1= 1600;
    enQueue(value1,valscor1);
    
    int valscor2= 95;
    enQueue(value1,valscor2);
    
    int valscor3= 110;
    enQueue(value1,valscor3);
    
    int valscor4= 123;
    enQueue(value1,valscor4);
    
    int valscor5= 12;
    enQueue(value1,valscor5);
    
    int valscor6= 44;
    enQueue(value1, valscor6);
    
    int valscor7= 11;
    enQueue(value1, valscor7);
    
    struct Node* head = front;

    //sorting and printing the first score (which should be eleven but it is 1600 right now
    selectionsort(head);
    displayQueue();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output, the lines that have a lot of 1600's in them are being printed inside selection sort. I tried to see what was the first element each step of my for loops. Below those numbers you can see the whole order of the list items. [my outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9pjC.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and post an [mcve]. Please post the list as text, not a link to an image of the text.

Comment: post output as text, avoid images

Comment: See [why linked list are not sorted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65728316/why-linked-list-are-not-sorted)

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, I will be more careful next time. The question is answered btw if any other person has the same mistake I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to repoint `second` to `first->next`.

```
void selectionsort(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *first,*second,*temp;
    
    int i,j,N;
    N= 7;
    printf("%u\n",front->score);
    
    first = head;
    second = first->next;
    
    for(i=0;i<N-1;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<N;j++){
            if(first->score > second->score){
                swap(first,second);
            }
            second = second->next;
            printf("%u\n",front->score);
        }
        first = first->next;
        second = first->next;  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Please add this one.
        printf("%u\n",front->score);
    }
    printf("%u\n",front->score);
}
```

Comment: It baffles me how simple my mistake was. Thank you!

Comment: @bugraGundogan Glad that I could help. Good luck!